# Powershell, output AD info into a specific line

Tags: powershell

I am looking to create a PowerShell script that outputs AD information into a specific line.
I am still researching this question but thought asking would yield some results.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
cls
$sid = Read-Host 'What is the username?'
Get-ADUser $sid -Properties * | Select-Object '$nm = GivenName' , Surname, SamAccountName, DisplayName,
City, EmailAddress, EmployeeID, Enabled, OfficePhone, MobilePhone, LockedOut, LockOutTime, AccountExpirationDate, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet

cls

Write-Host Name: 
Write-Host Email:  
Write-Host Phone:  
Write-Host User ID:  
Write-Host BlueWeb ID:  
Write-Host Vendor:  
Write-Host Plan:  
Write-Host Location:  
Write-Host PC_Name/Type:  
Write-Host Issue/Request:  
Write-Host Previous Ticket:  
Write-Host Application:  
Write-Host Troubleshooting:  
Write-Host Issue after troubleshooting:
```

I think I am close to what I am doing with the GivenName as a test. I am looking to output the results of Get-ADUser, to the Write-Host fields.
Anyway, any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Not at all sure what you mean by _AD information into a specific line_.. Are you expecting the output from the Read-Host can be used as `-Identity` for the Get-ADUser ?? I think you should read more about [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps), especially the `-Filter` and `-Identity` parameters. Next, read about [Calculated Properties](https://4sysops.com/archives/add-a-calculated-property-with-select-object-in-powershell/) in combination with `Select-Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy for some of the output, simply do this:

```
$object = Get-ADUser $sid -Properties * | Select-Object '$nm = GivenName' , Surname, 
SamAccountName, DisplayName,
City, EmailAddress, EmployeeID, Enabled, OfficePhone, MobilePhone, LockedOut, 
LockOutTime, AccountExpirationDate, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet
```

And then use the $object variable to reference all the parameters, like so:

```
Write-Host $object.Surname
Write-Host $object.EmailAddress
Write-Host $object.City
```

You can only reference what is in the parameter list. So I don't know how you would output Issue/Request, Previous Ticket, etc. Because this info is not fetched with the Get-ADUser command.

Comment: any tips to keep the format and append the output?
Write-Host Name: William Christner
Write-Host Email:  email@email.com
Write-Host Phone:  555-555-5557
Write-Host User ID:  cw308186